# mysql inner join with null select results?

Tags: mysql

Honestly, I'm not even sure I'm phrasing this correctly. I'm inner joining 3 tables and the third I need to check if there's not an entry there that matches a certain id. Here's where I'm at so far:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE b.status=1 AND
IS NULL (SELECT c.* FROM tableC c WHERE c.userID=a.userID c.otherID=3)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You should at least put the IS NULL *after* the value that you want to test for null. So after your subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA a INNER JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE b.status=1 AND
      not exists (SELECT 1 FROM tableC c WHERE c.userID = a.userID and c.otherID = 3)
```

The subquery with `(select * . . . )` would not be correct.  `is null` (which should be afterwards) is expecting a scalar value.  For a subquery to return a scalar value, it needs to return one row and one column.

Also, the `where` clause needs a conjunction between the two conditions.  I made it `and`.

In any case, `not exists` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
SELECT a.* FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.userID = b.userID
INNER JOIN tableC c ON c.userID=a.userID and c.otherID!=3
WHERE b.status=1
```

Comment: I understand where the c.otherID!=3 would work in some cases, but with this particular one it could return many other results where otherID may equal 4,5 and 6. Not sure if that explains it well, but thanks for the reply anyways :)